# How to fix OpenSUSE Docker installation not using all available storage

Tags: linux, docker, storage, opensuse

I have spent the past several days desperately trying to fix rampant issues including constant `no space left on device` errors, containers malfunctioning (when they need to use more disk space), and general issues with what would seem to be a lack of storage. The thing is, I have *hundreds* of gigabytes of storage available, as well as more than enough inodes. Also of note is the fact that, after fixing another, similar issue, I no longer get these errors and problems when running non-Docker commands and processes.

From fiddling around with the Docker installation, I have gotten the impression that Docker is imposing some sort of storage limit on itself (seems to be around 40 GB, maybe?), as cleaning up the Docker installation temporarily fixes the issue, but the issue reappears when more images/containers/etc. are added.

Here is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         18G     0   18G   0% /dev
tmpfs            18G     0   18G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            18G   26M   18G   1% /run
tmpfs            18G     0   18G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /tmp
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /usr/local
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /.snapshots
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /root
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /opt
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /srv
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /var
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
/dev/sda1        40G   39G  680M  99% /boot/grub2/i386-pc
/dev/sda3       390G  430M  389G   1% /home
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/0735e91a5a94abd2d35e8724d497b7b17fd47d961cd3675530b649e2ef41a994/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/d7872bfc37a924c01467a968d50b90ebf67f399f063cef19ec63da575c25e3bd/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/c268324c566fb3c2ca0c35cd9ffdc2098091b85ef562edc8cac1a526558cd915/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/428a97e7b27af2ce4993958d079f9fc5213826711e1230915085d78d4999d55f/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/971137d0c07e59f5ffec7f1b05526140f63a936b717a4a01010c59d54bc2489d/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/bb68ed0847455de5860a240b34d6deb33d6644437a763d0b4592232e136f880e/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e91e711f21597aa8523c1132bd19ab977657d4a830810dd636945ff7214b3224/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5349e122ee53da19fb654d126a10cc1a2db82e80be81afa158be0fd101e33d83/shm
shm              64M   64K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/9ff03bb3c21e6b77b24a94207213e6cfd3f4b2a96d5a4e06c117119ffe417719/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/f677ee4c43a1ddc4a70fdc37de1e600cc2dfa090be8237f76bad9f8731dd109b/shm
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /run/user/0
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e650b70591ba2e7a4096fe64920d249493db2e45fccec2918f2f41dc2b153fc8/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/652bd601b42071ce80149d53950fe37f5ebe5457b7dade9195d51867662307fd/shm
```

Here is the output of `docker info`:

```
Containers: 14
 Running: 12
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 13
Server Version: 17.09.1-ce
Storage Driver: btrfs
 Build Version: Btrfs v4.15
 Library Version: 102
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: oci runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: v0.1.3_catatonit (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.12.14-lp150.11-default
Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.0
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 35.34GiB
Name: server-PowerEdge-2900
ID: I7RS:QXXH:TCXR:S55J:ANEW:ESA4:MLWL:FXQ5:TNKX:NY5O:B3GZ:GGGG
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: phyremaster
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the explanation for this is actually pretty simple; I'm surprised the Internet is completely devoid of answers to this question.

Basically, by default, Docker uses `/var/lib/docker/` to store all containers, images, and volumes. In many cases, this is just fine. If you have large volumes, though, you will probably run into issues. Why? Well, in most Linux distributions (including OpenSUSE), the vast, vast majority of available disk space is allocated exclusively to the `/home` partition, leaving only (in my case) about 40 GB for files in other folders, including `/var/lib/docker/`. My Docker installation *was* actually running out of space, but not disk space; it was running out of *partition* space.

All that said, there's still one important question: how does one actually fix this? There are many options:

- Personally, I decided to copy the contents of each volume's `_data` folder to new folders within my home folder and then change all of my containers' volumes into bind mounts to the new folders.
- Alternatively, you could edit your Docker installation's configuration, changing the main storage location from `/var/lib/docker/` to a folder in your home directory (making sure to copy the contents from `/var/lib/docker/` to the new folder.
- Yet another possible solution would be to increase the size of the root partition.

These fixes are listed in order from easiest but worst to hardest but best. No matter what you do, be careful, and **back up your data!** When messing around with these things, it is very easy to accidentally delete important files.

Comment: This is why I should have gotten a proper education in Linux before getting into all of this industrial grade hardware and software...